# Encoding/decoding NSImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, file-io, encoding

I'm working on an OSX app and need to save a custom class's information, so I am trying to index it using NSCoder; however, one of the objects I'm trying to encode/decode in the class is an NSImage, and every time i try to run encodeWithCoder: or initWithCoder: I one of these two error messages:

`Warning - attempting to encode NSCGSImageRep`
`Warning - attempting to decode NSCGSImageRep`

Here's my .m:

```
@implementation Subject

-(id) init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.ad = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        self.editViewController = self.ad.editViewController;
        self.name = @"";
        self.teacher = @"";
        self.mainPeriod = 1;
    }

    return self;
}
-(void) encodeWithCoder: (NSCoder *) coder{
    [coder encodeObject:self.name forKey:@"name"];
    [coder encodeObject:self.teacher forKey:@"teacher"];
    NSNumber *periodNumBox = [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.mainPeriod];
    [coder encodeObject:periodNumBox forKey:@"mainPeriod"];
    [coder encodeObject:self.image forKey:@"image"];
}
-(id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *) coder{
    self.name = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];
    self.teacher = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"teacher"];
    NSNumber *periodNumBox = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"mainPeriod"];
    self.mainPeriod = (int)[periodNumBox integerValue];
    self.image = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"image"];
    return self;
}
@end
```

and my .h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "EditViewController.h"

@class EditViewController;

@interface Subject : NSObject

@property (weak) AppDelegate *ad;
@property EditViewController *editViewController;

@property NSImage *image;
@property NSString *name;
@property NSString *teacher;
@property int mainPeriod;

@end
```

Comment: check this one, this may help you [write NSImage to file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038820/how-to-save-a-nsimage-as-a-new-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't quite what you're asking, but it might be a solution worth considering: don't. If the image is guaranteed to exist elsewhere at decode time, all you need to archive is the *name* or other *reference* to the image. If the image is not guaranteed to exist elsewhere at decode time, then save it to disk where it *will* be guaranteed to exist, and archive the *name* or other *reference* to it.

Please see also my answer here on how to transform an image to NSData:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15694549/341994

NSData can be written directly to a file on disk. Of course, since an NSData object is archivable, you could now put it in an archive; it will work with encoding and decoding. But I would still argue that you should prefer not to do so.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS 10.15 I can encode NSImages without Problems.