# How to upload images to azure without losing quality with image data swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, azure, azure-blob-storage

Currently, I am using below to upload an image in Azure blob

```
  let im:UIImage = catImage[i]
            let imageData = im.pngData()
            blob.upload(from: imageData!, completionHandler:{(NSError) -> Void in
                print( i , "uploaded")

                print(blob.metadata)
                print(i , imageData)
            })
```

but I am losing image quality because of pngdata().
What else I can use without losing quality.

Comment: show the code where you use pngData

Comment: @Scriptable let imageData = im.pngData() // im is an UIImage

Comment: it would be much better if you could provide a sample image, or a link to sample image. convert it to data, compare that data size with the result of pngData() in the question.

Comment: @Scriptable have you ever faced above problem?

Comment: No, not really. It could be being compressed by the service on Azure that receives the file? (i'm not familiar with Azure blob?) .pngData should return the same quality image

Comment: Not sure what your specific issue is, but Azure has nothing to do with compressed data; blobs are just... objects. It knows nothing of your contents, and doesn't alter *any* contents. Your issue is going to be related to the image library / tools you're working with.

Comment: @Scriptable - Azure Storage does no such thing. Blobs in Azure Storage are just objects. They are never altered from what is sent to / retrieved from them.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I will check once again in my code about the specific issue and will update here

Comment: @DavidMakogon please check my edited code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with my image picker, solved it by picking phasset instead of images directly

Answer (score 0):

Similar question here: [UIImage to raw NSData / avoid compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693965/uiimage-to-raw-nsdata-avoid-compression)

Trying to save a UIImage without compression.